# How can I configure Android Studio to get rid of these errors?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling

After attempting to import a project into my version of android studio, I was bombarded with the following errors:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In order to mitigate this, I set my android studio project to android sdk 26 but it's failed to mitigate the issue. I've also tried updating the build gradle but that also has yet to produce promising results.

Here's an area in which I've received an error:

```
boolean workerStarted = false;
        boolean workerAdded = false;
        Worker w = null;
        try {
            w = new Worker(firstTask);
            final Thread t = w.thread;
            if (t != null) {
                final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
                mainLock.lock();
                try {
                    // Recheck while holding lock.
                    // Back out on ThreadFactory failure or if
                    // shut down before lock acquired.
                    int rs = runStateOf(ctl.get());

                    if (rs < SHUTDOWN ||
                        (rs == SHUTDOWN && firstTask == null)) {
                        if (t.isAlive()) // precheck that t is startable
                            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
                        workers.add(w);
                        int s = workers.size();
                        if (s > largestPoolSize)
                            largestPoolSize = s;
                        workerAdded = true;
                    }
                } finally {
                    mainLock.unlock();
                }
                if (workerAdded) {
                    t.start();
                    workerStarted = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

I expect to run my build and the error message above is what I got instead.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:201)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:867)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:194)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Ahers\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Ahers\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ -D \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.cupidlove -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:865)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Ahers\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Ahers\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ -D \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.cupidlove -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Ahers\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:382)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
```

Comment: Look at the rest of the stacktrace, particularly any "Caused by", which should show the actual cause of the error.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
 at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:201)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)

Comment: That's what the caused by said but the files its reffering to seem be fine.

Comment: Edit the question and show the ***full*** stacktrace, not just the first "Caused by". Show all of them.

Comment: ok, sure thing:)

Comment: Is this your personal project or some sample from github or somewhere else. If so can you share the link ?

Comment: Also what do you mean by **"I've also tried updating the build gradle but that also has yet to produce promising results."** ?

Comment: It's a personal project, may I send you the source?

Comment: @MikePence have you tried my suggested workarounds? You can also share your source code with me so that I can try fixing the issue.

Comment: Hi. @Roaim . I tried a lot of your suggestions but I still wasn't able to get around it.  I'd be more than happy to send you my source code. Is there another platform you'd like to move to for this?

Comment: you can host your project on GitHub and share the link to me. you can also connect me on https://linkedin.com/in/roaim

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I've sent you an invite on LinkedIn. I can send you everything from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your stack trace, it can be guessed that the error is due to the Android Resources or more specifically within the XML files as it says,

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'
```

After going further, we can see -

```
Error while executing process C:\Users\Ahers\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Ahers\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ -D \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.cupidlove -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\codecanyon-wL3wOIIS-cupid-love-dating-native-android-application\MainFile\CupidLove\Androidapp\CuipdLove_paid_feature_added\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
```

I can give you the following suggestions by analyzing the above error message,

- We can see the build tool version is 26.0.2. Make sure Compile and target SDK versions are not higher than it. Try to keep them in the same version. If the project has multiple modules then check if all the module has the same version. Also try to match the Gradle versions.
- As we can see aapt is throwing the error while processing the AndroidManifest.xml file, then the most possible reason could be any malformed entry in this file. Therefore I would suggest you to go through each and every line in the manifest file (including all flavors). Especially check the proper implementation of 3rd party SDKs entries in Manifest across all the flavors.
- Try to clean the project from the build menu and invalidate the cache and restart from the file menu.
- Last but not least, try to build your app from the Gradle toolbar on the right side of the android studio's default window. Choose your **module** -> **Tasks** -> **build** -> **build** . By doing so you will probably get more details logs in the run tab. Which will help you debug quickly.

Comment: Thanks again for everything!